# Running a Yaml script that does it's job but it keeps giving me a syntax error

Tags: database, ansible, yaml, mariadb

Ok so i'm running this script, which works, it does what i want: Connecting to all Routers, interogating the equip and storing the data in a database, but it harrases me that i get that syntax error.
The error is: `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'EOF' at line 1`

I'm using MariaDB, tried various answers from the internet and still did not solve it.

```
- name: Connect to equipment and verify the status of routing table Conectare la echipamnete si verificare status tabela de rutare
  hosts: "router"
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
  - name: Use show ip route command
    ios_command:
      commands: show ip route | begin Gateway of last

    register: output

  - name: Importa output catre baza de date controlnodedb
    shell: |
     mariadb -u ansible controlnodedb << EOF
     INSERT INTO ROUTE_TABLE (Device_Hostname,RouteTable) VALUES ("{{ inventory_hostname }}","{{ output.stdout }}");
     EOF
```

...

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [`stdin:` module parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/shell_module.html#parameters):

```yaml
  - name: Importa output catre baza de date controlnodedb
    shell: mariadb -u ansible controlnodedb
    stdin: >-
       INSERT INTO ROUTE_TABLE (Device_Hostname,RouteTable)
       VALUES ("{{ inventory_hostname }}","{{ output.stdout }}");
```

to get away from the indentation error caused by `EOF` not appearing where the shell is expecting.

Actually, the *real solution* would be to [create a dedicated ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#adding-a-module-locally) that would use the [Python DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) to avoid SQL injection problems where you are just inserting `output.stdout` and `inventory_hostname` directly into SQL literals (which, maybe MySQL tolerates, but the [Maria DB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/string-literals/) says to use single quotes, not double quotes, for string literals)